# Bash script to edit a bunch of files

Tags: bash, batch-processing

To process a bunch of data and get it ready to be inserted into our database, we generate a bunch of shell scripts.  Each of them has about 15 lines, one for each table that the data is going.  One a recent import batch, some of the import files failed going into one particular table.  So, I have a bunch of shell scripts (about 600) where I need to comment out the first 7 lines, then rerun the file.  There are about 6000 shell scripts in this folder, and nothing about a particular file can tell me if it needs the edit.  I've got a list of which files that I pulled from the database output.

So how do I write a bash script (or anything else that would work better) to take this list of file names and for each of them, comment out the first 7 lines, and run the script?

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
cmd4
cmd5
cmd6
cmd7
cmd8
```

Not sure how readable that is.  Basically, the first 7 lines (not counting the first line) need to have a # added to the beginning of them.  Note: the files have been edited to make each line shorter and partially cut off copying out of VIM.  But in the main part of each file, there is a line starting with echo, then a line starting with sqlldr

Comment: provide samples of input files, and describe clearly how you want the output, if any, to be like...

Comment: Edited to include sample file.

Comment: For posterity: you need to do chmod +x line.new as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sed, you can specify a line number range in the file to be changed.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    # add a comment to beginning of lines 1 - 7 and rename the script
    sed '3,9 s/^/#/' $line > $line.new
    exec $line.new
done < "filelist.txt"
```

You may wish to test this before running it on all of those scripts...

EDIT: changed the lines numbers to reflect comments.

Comment: ?s: 
1) ^ is the special character for beginning of line?
2) Is 1 the first line, or 0 the first line of a file?
3) How can this be set up to take as input the list of files to change?  IE how do I tell the while read line to pull from the file list?  Is it as simple as putting the list of files in a file and redirecting input from that file?

Comment: ^ is the character that represents the beginning of a line. 1 is the first line.  This will read a file "filelist.txt" line by line and change each file in that list.  This will only change lines 1-7 as requested - including the first line.  The numbers at the beginning can be adjusted to accommodate what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you opening "filelist.tx" or is it being piped or redirected into the script?

Comment: This opens the file "filelist.txt" and reads it line by line.

Comment: I think you want to put that "exec $line.new" in a subshell.

Comment: ok, somebody fill me in on what filelist.txt is?? if OP is going to modify 600 shell scripts, then just sed '1,7 s/^/#/' *.sh will do. There is no need for the while loop. am i missing something?

Comment: You want to do lines 3-9 so you don't comment out the shebang and the blank line.

Comment: @ghostdog:  there are 600 shell scripts i need to change, but 6000 or so in the folder.  So I can't do do that.
@Dennis Yeah, I'll be adjusting the line numbers to skip those.

Comment: Yes, I will be testing this quite a bit before I hit go :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is how I understand it... The while loop is a statement in scripting.  This takes the contents of that file and redirects them into the while loop where they are read line by line into the variable $line.  Someone else could explain this better than me, I think...

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"
do
    out=/tmp/$file.$$
    sed '2,8s/^/#/' < $file > $out
    $SHELL $out
    rm -f $out
done
```

Assuming you don't care about checking for race conditions etc.

Comment: What could cause race conditions in this situation?  Would that only occur if multiple instances of this script were running at the same time?

Comment: Multiple instances of _this_ script should be okay (that's what the $$ is for, it adds the process id to files).  The problem is a malicious user who creates a bunch of readonly /tmp/foo.[range of guesses at your pid] files with stuff they want to execute using your privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you're going to want to use the linux command sed.  Whatever logic you need to place in the script, you know.  But your script will ultimately call sed.  http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-sed.html

Answer (score 1):

ex seems made for what you want to do.

For instance, for editing one file, with a here document:

```
#!/bin/sh

ex test.txt << END
1,12s/^/#/
wq
END
```

That'll comment out the first 12 lines in "test.txt". For your example you could try `"$FILE"` or similar (including quotes!).

Then run them the usual way, i.e. `./"$FILE"`

edit: `$SHELL "$FILE"` is probably a better approach to run them (from one of the above commenters).